# Dot Tool BinarySearchTree Java

Tags: java

I simply try to write to a dot file following addition of integers to a BinarySearchTree, but no file is generated to the project file upon execution.

```
 public void testadd()
{
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> bst = new BinarySearchTree<Integer>();

    bst.add(1);
    bst.add(2);
    bst.add(3);
    bst.add(4);
    bst.add(5);

    bst.writeDot("BST.dot");
}
```

Comment: What library (package) is `BinarySearchTree` part of? The implementation of the `writeDot()` method will determine what its output should be, and whether or not you can expect a file to be created or not.

Comment: None of the code you provided should write to a file. We need to see the portion which is supposed to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static PrintStream out;

public void writeToFile( ) throws IOException{
         out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("BST.dot")); 
         writeToFile(root);
         out.close();
}

public void writeToFile(BinaryTreeNode  t) throws IOException
{


            if (t != null)
            {
                System.setOut(out);   
                System.out.println(t.info);
                writeToFile(t.left); 
                writeToFile(t.right);

            }
}
```